# JDBC ResultSet: not last but has not next, why?

Tags: jdbc, iterator, hsqldb

I am using HsqlDB 1.8.1, and found something strange:

```
ResultSet rs;
...
boolean isLast=rs.isLast();
assert !isLast;
boolean hasNext=rs.next();
assert hasNext;
```

In my case, `isLast` is false, but `hasNext` is also false! Can you tell me why? I think if the cursor is not on the last row of this resultset, then it should have next row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I take it you meant that your `hasNext` assertion is failing because `hasNext` is *false*, correct?

Is your `ResultSet` of type `TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY`? Per [the documentation for `ResultSet#isLast()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#isLast%28%29), support for this method is "optional" in that case, though it's not clear whether it being optional means that the method will throw `SQLFeatureNotSupportedException`, or just return false unconditionally.